# How do I interpret these rules for Drugs and Addiction?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, duration, medicine-and-drugs

One of the PCs is addicted to Aether. I have read the rules about [Drugs and Addiction](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Drugs%20and%20Addiction&Category=Advanced%20Topics) but I do not understand everything yet.

The rules for Moderate [Addiction](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Addiction&Category=Drugs%20and%20Addiction) state:

> **Type** disease, variable; **Save** variable
> **Onset** 1 day; **Frequency** 1/day
> **Effect** –2 penalty to Con and Str, target cannot naturally heal ability damage caused by the drug that caused this addiction; **Cure** 3 consecutive saves

The rules for [Aether](https://aonprd.com/Drugs.aspx?ItemName=Aether) are:

> **Type** drug (inhaled); **Addiction** moderate, Fortitude DC 16
> **Price** 20 gp
> **Effect** 1 hour; +1 caster level
> **Effect** 1d4 hours; user must make a caster check to cast spells, DC 15 + spell level
> **Damage** 1d2 Con damage

Let us say the guy is addicted and takes Aether in the morning.

- What negative effect will he have for what time? Is it -2 Con and Str
  for 1 day (because the Frequency is 1/day) and -1d2 Con for the first
  hour after he inhaled the drug?
- And how often does he have to take the drug if he is addicted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### As soon as the drug effects wear off or in 24 hours

This is described under the **Addiction** topic on [Drugs & Addiction rules](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/gameMasteryGuide/drugsAndAddiction.html):

> While a character is benefiting from the effects of the drug he is addicted to, he does not suffer the penalties of his addiction disease. While he still receives the benefits of the drug and takes ability damage as normal, the disease's effects are mitigated. **As soon as the drug's benefits expire, the disease's effects return**.

And on **Curing Addiction**:

> Unlike with other diseases, an addicted character can only **make a Fortitude save to overcome his addiction after a day of not taking the drug** he is addicted to.

Then it follows the normal rules for diseases, applying the effects on a failed save based on the **onset** and **frequency** properties of the drug. For most drugs, that means one Fortitude check per day.

Once the drug effects wear off, the character is fine for a day if he passes his initial save, after that, he must make daily Fortitude saves or suffer the effects of his addiction. If he fails his initial save, he suffers the addiction effects immediatelly.

If your character has a *Moderate Addiction* and fails a saving thrown after the effects of an *Aether* wears off, you take a **-2 penalty on Strength and Constitution and unable to heal the Constitution damage** caused by using Aether. And this can only be prevented by taking another dose of the drug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one additional question. What if he is addicted but has no drugs and misses the saving throws?

Comment: Happens the usual for missing a saving throw against a disease, you take the listed effect and all penalties associated with the disease/addiction. For instance, take  a -2 penalty on Str and Con and unable to heal the 1d2 Con damaged caused by using Aether.